# Visual Studio win32project control resizing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, controls, designer

I'm making this project on visual studio using only embedded resources dialogs and i have a hard time positioning & resizing the controls using that useless designer.
Is there anyway to resize the controls properly or do i have to do it at runtime ?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What's difficult to do? With that _useless_ designer you can position and size controls where you prefer (absolute positions). Of course if your control is resizable then you have to do it at run-time (by hand). You may want to take a look to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9434/Automatic-resizing-controls).

Comment: I didn't say that the controls are not resizable. The controls are not resized properly, i can't fit two controls together in one ligne for example. THE DESIGNER IS NOT AS ACCURATE AS THE .NET DESIGNER.

Comment: Designer is accurate as WinForms/WPF designers...what you don't have (without some code) are anchors and docking (but that's another story). What's different is just unit you position controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know,if you use MFC or windows SDK,you must compute controls' new size and change it at runtime.You can change controls' size by SetWindowPos(a windows api) at runtime.